# VPN in Swift - loadFromPreferences not running handler

Tags: swift, macos, vpn, ipsec

I am trying to connect programmatically to a VPN. I got the code below on this website: http://blog.moatazthenervous.com/create-a-vpn-connection-with-apple-swift/

I am trying to develop a command line application for macOS to connect programatically to a VPN.

```
import Foundation
import NetworkExtension

class VPN {

    let vpnManager = NEVPNManager.shared();
    let userName: String;
    let passString: String;
    let secret: String;
    let server: String;

    init (_ user: String, _ pass: String, _ secret: String, _ server: String){
        userName = user
        passString = pass
        self.secret = secret
        self.server = server
    }

    private var vpnLoadHandler: (Error?) -> Void { return
    { (error:Error?) in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            print("Could not load VPN Configurations")
            return;
        }
        print ("me! me! ")
        let p = NEVPNProtocolIPSec()
        p.username = self.userName
        p.serverAddress = self.server
        p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethod.sharedSecret

        let kcs = KeychainService();
        kcs.save(key: "SHARED", value: self.secret )
        kcs.save(key: "VPN_PASSWORD", value: self.passString)
            p.sharedSecretReference = kcs.load(key: "SHARED")
            p.passwordReference = kcs.load(key: "VPN_PASSWORD")
            p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
            p.disconnectOnSleep = false
            p.localIdentifier = "uio"
            self.vpnManager.protocolConfiguration = p
            self.vpnManager.localizedDescription = "Contensi"
            self.vpnManager.isEnabled = true
            self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: self.vpnSaveHandler)
        } }

            private var vpnSaveHandler: (Error?) -> Void { return
        { (error:Error?) in
            if (error != nil) {
            print("Could not save VPN Configurations")
            return
            } else {
            do {
            try self.vpnManager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
            } catch let error {
            print("Error starting VPN Connection \(error.localizedDescription)");
            }
            }
            }

            }

            public func connectVPN() {
            //For no known reason the process of saving/loading the VPN configurations fails.On the 2nd time it works
            do {
                self.vpnManager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: self.vpnLoadHandler)
               // self.vpnManager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: nil)

            } 
            }

            public func disconnectVPN() ->Void {
            self.vpnManager.connection.stopVPNTunnel()
            }

    public func status() -> NEVPNStatus {

        return vpnManager.connection.status
    }

}
```

My problem is that I my completion handlers are not working. Take the function `connectVPN()`, for instance. It's completion handler is `vpnLoadHandler`. However, I never get that handler executed. See the print statement on the handler? Nothing ever gets printed.

Reading Apple's documentation, I know that I have to configure XCode with an entitlement in order to allow VPN - I haven't got the "capabilities"-tab, so I don't know how to add that entitlement. I am not sure if that's the problem, since the app compiles file and executes. I just don't get the completion handler to execute.

So, basically:

- why isn't the handler being called? And what can I do to debug?
- Could this be due the lack an entitlement to allow the configuration of a personal vpn in xcode? If so, how can I configure that?

Best,

Francis

**UPDATE** I actually managed to create the entitlements file, and I guess it has the proper settings to allow a personal vpn. So I guess that part is solved. But why isn't the completion handler called?

Comment: So, Are you done with VPN integration?

Comment: Nope, gave up the project.

Comment: @francisaugusto which server you used?